# php Mysql how to mark origin when several WHERE's?

Tags: php, mysql, where-clause

I have a mysql request that goes like this:

```
$request = mysql_query (" 
    SELECT title 
    FROM mytable 
    WHERE (name LIKE '%word%' OR description LIKE '%word%' OR skills LIKE '%word%') 
");

$z=1;

while($result = mysql_fetch_array($request))
{
    $title[$z]=$result['title']);$z++;
};
```

Obviously, I want to display the titles of an entity where the name, description or skills of that entity row contains a specific word.

But, how can I tell if this title has been displayed because of a success result made on 'name', 'description' or 'skills'?

My script just can't make the difference.
of course I could create a request for each element but I have a lot of them.

Thank you.

**EDIT:**

Maybe it's me but this is the real request and it's not working yet:

```
<?php 

$requete3  = mysql_query("
    SELECT 
        denomination, 
        owners,
        description_".$get_lang.",
        CONCAT (
            IF (denomination LIKE '%".$search_word."%', '1', '0'),
            IF (owners LIKE '%".$search_word."%', '1', '0'),
            IF (description_".$get_lang." LIKE '%".$search_word."%', '1', '0')
        ) AS match_bitmask
    FROM element1_entities 
    WHERE 
    (
        denomination LIKE '%".$search_word."%' OR 
        owners LIKE '%".$search_word."%' OR 
        description_".$get_lang." LIKE '%".$search_word."%'
    )
    AND f_filter_types_entities_id=2
    ORDER BY id DESC 
");

?>
```

As soon as I get rid of the CONCAT part, the error message disappears.
I also tried different parentheses configurations around and within but with no success.
I probably did something wrong.

Comment: select name description and skills also and check in php if they match %word%

Comment: Ok thank you. But is there no mysql command to make that distinction without an extra step involving filtering through PHP?

Comment: What if `name` and `description` both match `%word%`

Comment: I could use the info but if it marks the first encountered success only, I could live with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this - although you're pushing some processing into the query...

```
SELECT 
title, 
CONCAT(
    (IF (name LIKE '%word%', '1', '0')),
    (IF (description LIKE '%word%', '1', '0')),
    (IF (skills LIKE '%word%', '1', '0'))
) AS match_bitmask

FROM mytable 
WHERE (name LIKE '%word%' OR description LIKE '%word%' OR skills LIKE '%word%')
```

That should give you a sort of binary bitmask providing information about where the matches are found.

So a match on `name` and `skills` would give you `101` in a column called `match_bitmask` which you can access in your PHP loop.

Once inside the loop you've essentially got 3 columns in your bitmask with **name** on column '4' (the first column of the bitmask), **description** on column '2' (the 2nd column) and **skills** on column '1' (the third column).

You can then evaluate where the result was matched with:

```
$iBitmask = (int) $result['match_bitmask'];
$iDecimalmask = bindec($iBitmask);

// if `name` matches
if($iDecimalmask & 4) {
  ... do stuff ...
}

// if `description` matches
if($iDecimalmask & 2) {
  ... do stuff ...
}

// if `skills` matches
if($iDecimalmask & 1) {
  ... do stuff ...
}
```

Comment: Nice! I will give it a try and come back to check as resolved if it worked. Thank you

Comment: ... had to make a slight edit as there were some misplaced parentheses originally :\

Comment: I made the changes according to your original and edited script but I still get a "mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource". And if I get rid of the concat part, the error message goes away...

Comment: Odd - have it working on my local server (well, an edited version to match one of my tables) ... maybe your version of MySQL wants to evaluate the `IF`s first ... I'll chuck some more parentheses in and see if that sorts it.

Comment: I edited my question in order to see my real request. Do you see something wrong?

Comment: @Baylock I don't see anything immediately obvious with the syntax (as long as the interpolated PHP variables are all present and correct) ... I'd write it differently and use PDO with bound parameters since the `mysql` library is basically defunct now ... but I can't see a problem with the syntax which would cause it to fall over at the moment.

Comment: Silly as usual. Not obvious at first sight but there can't be any space between the word "CONCAT" and the opening parenthese. Your request is just perfect. As are the other participants ones. Thank you all!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
title, 
CASE WHEN name LIKE '%word%' then 'Name'
     WHEN description like '%word%' then 'Description'
     ELSE 'Skills'
END CASE as match_column

FROM mytable 
WHERE (name LIKE '%word%' OR description LIKE '%word%' OR skills LIKE '%word%')
```

I think I like CD001's answer better, but this is another option.

Answer (score 1):

It is a problem regarding SQL, not php itself. The first solution I can suggest is using "CASE" syntax.

You can edit your query in the following way:

```
SELECT title,
       CASE
            WHEN name LIKE '%word%' THEN 'name'
            WHEN description LIKE '%word%' THEN 'description'
            WHEN skills LIKE '%word%' THEN 'skills'
       END AS field,
       ...
FROM mytable 
WHERE (name LIKE '%word%' OR description LIKE '%word%' OR skills LIKE '%word%')
```

so you'll have title and the reference of where word was found.

Comment: concurrent posting... same solution as above :)

Comment: That's ok, I'll look into it but, if it works, the solution of CD001 suits my needs better. If not, I'll give yours a try. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid php filtering you can use a variant of my solution with CASE:

```
SELECT
   CASE
        WHEN name LIKE '%word%' THEN CONCAT('name: ', title)
        WHEN description LIKE '%word%' THEN CONCAT('description: ', title)
        WHEN skills LIKE '%word%' THEN CONCAT('skills: ', title)
   END AS title,
   FROM mytable 
   WHERE (name LIKE '%word%' OR description LIKE '%word%' OR skills LIKE '%word%')
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution... with sqlfiddle!

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e6929/5

Similar to some of the others, but this one will return a space separated list of ANY matching terms as `matches`.

It looks a bit more complex, but just because I use a `CONCAT('%', @word, '%')` in several places so I can use the @word var just once.

```
set @word = 'fox';

SELECT title, 
CONCAT( 
 IF(title LIKE CONCAT('%', @word, '%'),'title ',''),
 IF(description LIKE CONCAT('%', @word, '%'),'desc ',''),
 IF(skills LIKE CONCAT('%', @word, '%'),'skills','')
  )
AS matches
FROM mytable 
WHERE  title LIKE CONCAT('%', @word, '%')
       OR description LIKE CONCAT('%', @word, '%')
       OR skills LIKE CONCAT('%', @word, '%')
```

Gives results like:

```
TITLE   MATCHES
------  ------
test    desc
fox     title skills
```

Comment: it works, thank you. I clicked the CD001 answer as a solution because I was working on it but your answer is just fine, thank you